# Getting the input value for React Bootstrap FormControl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have spent more than a day on what is probably going to be a very simple solution. I am using react-bootstrap.

I have a form that looks like this:

**modal_form.js.jsx**

```
...
render: function() {
  var Modal = require('react-bootstrap').Modal;
  var InputField = app.InputField
  var formElementsCollection= this.props.formElements.map((formElement, i) => {
    return (
      <InputField
        inputControlID="myInput"
        inputLabel="Input Label"
        placeholderText="My Placeholder"
        key={i}
        />
    )
  });

  return (
    <Modal
      keyboard={true}
      show={this.props.showModal}
      onHide={this.props.unloadModal}
      >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <h3>
          {this.props.headerText}
        </h3>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <form>
          {formElementsCollection}
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right" onClick={() => this.props.onClickHandler(this)}>{this.props.buttonText}</button>
        </form>
        <div className="clearfix"></div>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
}
...
```

**input_field.js.jsx**

```
...
handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
},

render: function() {
  var FormGroup = require('react-bootstrap').FormGroup;
  var ControlLabel = require('react-bootstrap').ControlLabel;
  var FormControl = require('react-bootstrap').FormControl;
  return (
    <FormGroup
        controlId={this.props.inputControlID}
      >
      <ControlLabel>{this.props.inputLabel}</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl
        type="text"
        value={this.state.value}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholderText}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <FormControl.Feedback />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
...
```

As you can see, I am mapping out an array of values in my ModalForm parent and the creating an InputField child for each mapped value of the array. In the InputField child component, I then assign the value state of each element by making use of an 'onChange' method callback.

What I'm struggling to understand, is how to get the value of each of the InputField child components in my parent component? Since I'm using react-bootstrap and it's FormControl component, I do not have a 'ref' attribute to call. I'm not sure this is something that I need to explicitly define, but since the react-bootstrap docs don't provision for this attribute, I figured that there must be a better way of obtaining each value? Am I wrong in this assumption?